# What does IIS do when \\?\c:\filename instead of pulling an actual path

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying run an api on IIS, but when ever I try to use the IIS manager I get this error on it not sure what it is trying to point to with \?\c:\ all of my other co-workers do not have this issue with IIS.

[image: IIS Error]

[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html#background You hit the famous OOB issue, so just need to learn what is the OOB component you didn't install.

Comment: Please show your web.config to check if there any format error. Did you set url rewrite rule in web.config but did not install url rewrite module on IIS?

Comment: @BruceZhang I added a screenshot of the webconfig in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Please install url rewrite on IIS. Download it from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).